# Sketch the domain of this function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to sketch the domain of the function: $f(x,y) = y^2 + $ln$(x^2)-1$

The function is defined for all $y$ and $x$ except when $x=0$. I want to show this on a graph so that I can graphically show the domain.

I just wanted to check that the sketch I have in mind is correct:

I would just plot the $x=0$ line and then my domain is everything either side of this line, correct?
[image]

I know this question might be really simple and may just be a yes/no answer but I just want to make sure I've got this right since I've struggled a bit with domains of multivariable function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's quite correct.

Comment: Ok great, Thank you

Comment: @Bernard And how would I write the range of the function? Is it just $(-\infty , \infty)$ excluding $0$? Or is there another way I should write it?

Comment: Personally, I would write it $\mathbf R^*\!\times\mathbf R$.

Comment: What does the $R$ with the asterix mean? Does it mean all real values except $0$?

Comment: As  in all fields, $\mathbf R\smallsetminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks a lot

Comment: @L.F.:  the  line in red is  $x=0$.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry, was daydreaming.

Comment: That's what all mathematicians do…